# open&edit winscp folder in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor, winscp

I'm developing on ubuntu server, and since I want to use atom as text editor,
I've been using winscp.
However, it was very inconvenient since I had to click each file on winscp to open the file with atom.
What I want is to add a whole project folder in winscp to atom editor, and whenever I save file on atom, it automatically uploads to server. I want to use options provided by atom such as "Save All" or "Find in Project", but opening each single file on winscp forbids me from using these options.

Is there a way to add a whole folder from server and let the server reflects all data I saved on atom editor?
Thank you :)

Comment: how can you use winscp on Ubuntu?

Comment: Oh I'm a window user, but the server (connected by port) I'm using to save and render files is ubuntu.

Comment: so you're developing on *Windows* and remoting to Linux. The Ubuntu server just stores the files. In that case simply mount the samba share to Windows, or ssh into Ubuntu and develop there

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use these plugins:

1) [remote-edit](https://atom.io/packages/remote-edit)

2) [Ftp-Remote-Edit](https://atom.io/packages/ftp-remote-edit)